# Handling Form to submit API call and display API result in the same page

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Form to get data and from that data, I will use a specific solution API to create a site using the information from this form.

I would like to get the data from this form, create the site using the APIs, but I would like to get the API result data and display the content on the same form page but below the submit bottom.

I was able to create the basic form, get the necessary data and create the site using API call, but I have no idea what I have to do to get the API result and display it in case of success. ``

```
class SiteForm(forms.Form):
    site_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Site Name",
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Demo API'}))
    country = forms.CharField(label="Country",
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Country',}))
    time_zone = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Timezone",
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City'}))

    location = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Location",
                               widget=forms.TextInput(
                                   attrs={'placeholder': 'Street'}))
```

I don't know if this is the best code, but the POST is working at least, I can create my site using the API call.
My views.py

```
class SiteCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'site_config.html'
    form_class = SiteForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return render(request)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        site_info = {}
        site_info['name'] = request.POST.get("site_name")
        site_info['timezone'] = request.POST.get("country")
        site_info['country_code'] = request.POST.get("time_zone")
        site_info['address'] = request.POST.get("location")

        data_post = json.dumps(site_info)
        token = '<token-id>'
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
        }
        url = '<API URL>'

        response = requests.post(url, data=data_post, headers=headers)

        new_site_info = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())
```

This is my basic .html

```
{% extends 'site_base.html'%}
{% block title %}Site Config{% endblock title%}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Create Site</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: is the api url your own application or a third party thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the class based views, but I suspect you can do something like:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data_post, headers=headers)
# get the normal context
context = self.get_context_data()
# add the results from the api
context['new_site'] = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
# hand off the normal with a new key for the new_site data
return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

then in your template something like:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Create Site</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
    </form>
    {% if new_site %}
       {{ new_site.some_attribute }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for that! It worked, but I have an additional question that I'm struggling to understand here.
Why your code redirect the result to the same page and this one below doesn't?

```
new_site = response.json()
return render(request, self.template_name, {
    'name': new_site
})
```

Comment: The `self.` I suspect